# How to copy a directory using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have used `copydir` to copy a directory tree but it is deprecated. My directory contains some sub-directories, and some of those contain files and others contain more sub-directories.

How can I copy the entire tree?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a recursive copy.  And that's the solution that Omnipresent gave.  More people may find this question if the word "recursive" appeared in the question.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" >  
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**"/>  
</copy>
```

believe that will do what you want... (Recursive copy done)

Comment: apparently, the `includes` is not necessary when you want everything (see answer by user *s1n*)

Comment: This copies the contents of {src.dir}, but not the actual directory

Comment: Copies not a did but it's content.

Comment: Since you are the accepted answer, you might correct it to become the correct answer (ery's answer is correct) ;-)

Comment: I gather that the idea of SO is collective curation, which is why anyone can edit someone else's question (though you need a lot of rep to skip the edit review).

Comment: The accepted answer isn't supposed to be the correct answer but merely the answer that helped OP. Changing the essence of an accepted isn't necessarily a good idea. Answer that receives most points is supposed to be the right answer.

Answer (score 129):

Copy contents including the directory itself.

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" >  
    <fileset dir="${src.dir.parent}">  
        <include name="${src.dir}/**"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Note: ${src.dir} is relative to ${src.dir.parent}, and not a full path

Comment: this should be the CORRECT answer. The other answer are for the question "How do you copy the contents of a directory using Ant". There is a subtle difference.

Comment: "this should be the CORRECT answer": Absolutely, though the difference is not so subtle when you can't load your resources with the expected pathnames.

Comment: it doesn't work for ant 1.8, it seems nothing happened.

Comment: @CCC ensure ${src.dir} is *relative* to ${src.dir.parent}, and not a full path

Comment: very misleading how `x.parent` is supposed to NOT BE the `parent` of `x`... -_-

Comment: Would be good to include the comment by @MikeDemenok. That worked for me and didn't work until I did that

Comment: hello can you please tell me how to use it

Answer (score 26):

You should only have to specify the directory (sans the includes property):

```
<copy todir="../new/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
</copy>
```

See the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) for more details and examples.

Comment: @s1n This commands only copies all the contents of src_dir to ../new/dir and not the src_dir. How do we copy src_dir (directory) to another location?

Answer (score 17):

Copy contents including the directory itself.

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" >  
  <fileset dir="${src.dir.parent}" includes="${src.dir}/**"/>
</copy>
```

Comment: This is the most succinct option.  See also  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html.

Answer (score 2):

A fine point: ant will only copy the sub-directories if the source files are newer than the destination files.  [[1]](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) In my case, the sub-dirs were not being copied (I am using verbose="true"), since there were no changes and they were already in the destination.  You can use "overwrite" to force it, or touch some of the files in your source sub-dirs.

Answer (score 2):

I used include tags as shown in below code snippet in my build.xml file to copy individul jar files inside a directory.

```
<target name="devInstall" depends="generateXsl" description="testing">
<copy flatten="true" todir="${test}/WEB-INF/lib" overwrite="${overwrite}">
                <fileset refid="buildJars"/>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="commons-collections-*.jar"/>
                    <include name="commons-io-*.jar"/>              
                    <include name="kodo/*.jar"/>
                    <include name="mail*.jar"/>    
                    <include name="activation*.jar"/>               
                    <include name="guava*.jar"/>
                    <include name="jna*.jar"/>                          
                </fileset>          
            </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the example [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), you can write a simple Ant file using copy task.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="copy" basedir=".">
    <target name="copy">
        <copy todir="./new/dir">
           <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

This should copy everything inside `src_dir` (excluding it) to `new/dir`.

Comment: this is just copying the contents of the directory. not the contents including the directly. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a more generic pattern to copy all subfolders.

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" >  
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
</copy>
```

See [Patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) for details.

Comment: what should i replace dest.dir and src.dir with. i have nearly 6 directories to be copied to dest dir  and make a war file and deply it in tomcat server

Comment: @deepakl.2000 - note the ${...} construct indicates we're working with an Ant variable you define in your script elsewhere. see https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties

Answer (score 1):

Another ant task is [Copydir](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copydir.html). The key part here is to include the name of the directory you want to copy after the dest directory. The sub-directories and files will be copied automatically.

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <copydir src="config" dest="${dist.dir}/config/"/>
</target>
```

Comment: From your link: **This task has been deprecated. Use the Copy task instead.**

Answer (score 0):

This code should copy the folder as well as its contents. It also uses the basename task to avoid having to do any manual path parsing.

```
<project name="Build" default="doCopy">
  <property name="source.dir" value="SourceDirPathGoesHere"/>
  <property name="dest.dir" value="DestinationDirPathGoesHere"/>
  <target name="doCopy">
    <basename property="source.dir.base.name" file="${source.dir}"/>
    <copy todir="${dest.dir}">
      <fileset dir="${source.dir}/.." includes="${source.dir.base.name}/**"/>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally copied using following code

```
<copy todir="${root.dir}/dist/src">  
                <fileset dir="${root.dir}/build/src" includes="**"/>  
            </copy>
```

This will copy the src folder from dist to build.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: it literally says it would copy the other way around though :P