# How do I use Ant to copy a folder?

Tags: ant, copy

I'm trying to copy a directory using the Ant `copy` task.

I am a newbie at Ant; my current solution is:

```
<copy todir="${release_dir}/lib">
   <fileset dir="${libpath}" />
</copy>
```

I'm wondering if there is a better and shorter way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I think you're missing your current solution.

Comment: You need to indent the code in order to include XML in your posts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, those are the examples from Ant documentation:

Copy a directory to another directory

```
<copy todir="../new/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir"/>   
</copy>
```

Copy a set of files to a directory

```
<copy todir="../dest/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir">
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>

<copy todir="../dest/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir" excludes="**/*.java"/>   
</copy>
```

Copy a set of files to a directory, appending .bak to the file name on the fly

```
<copy todir="../backup/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
  <globmapper from="*" to="*.bak"/>   
</copy>
```

Secondly, here is the whole [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) about copy task.

Answer (score 7):

Just because the docs were not very clear to me, and because the time I spent can serve others:

The docs say that this "copies a directory (dir1) to another directory (dest)":

```
<copy todir="../new/dest">
  <fileset dir="src/dir1"/>   
</copy>
```

Actually, this does *not* mean "*copy `dir1` inside `dest`*", but rather "*copy the contents of `dir1` inside `dest`*".

(In general, in Ant, the "root dir" of a [filesets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)  -as well at the `todir` attribute- is not considered as being part of the set itself.)

To place the directory `dir1` inside `dest` one has several alternatives (none totally satisfying to me - and I'd imagined that the new [DirSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) would help here, but no)

```
<copy todir="../new/dest/dir1">
  <fileset dir="src/dir1"/>   
</copy>
```

or

```
<copy todir="../new/dest">
  <fileset dir="src" includes="dir1/**"/>
</copy>
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685442/how-to-copy-the-directory-using-ant) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229599/copying-multiple-directories-and-contents-in-one-shot).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
<copy todir="directory/to/copy/to">
    <fileset dir="directory/to/copy/from"/>
</copy>
```

The ant manual is your friend: [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/), in this case: [Copy Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Answer (score 1):

From http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html:

```
<copy todir="../new/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
</copy>
```