# copying in build.xml using copydir command

Tags: ant, jenkins, build.xml

Iam using Jenkins to build my project. In build.xml, I have written the following code to copy the files from src to dest folder...

```
<copydir src="../image_files/Ace/drawable-hdpi" dest="../IgnitorACE/res/drawable-hdpi"/>
```

The problem is that, in src having the only two image files with same name as in dest folder but the pattern/design  of images are differnt. So, whenever i run my build, jenkins has to copy and replace the image files with new image but same name.

The above command is working but getting warning as

```
[copydir] DEPRECATED - The copydir task is deprecated.  Use copy instead.
[copydir] Copying 2 files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ace Build/IgnitorACE/res/drawable-hdpi
```

So, any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning *clearly* states that `[copydir] DEPRECATED - The copydir task is deprecated.  Use copy instead`, you should use `copy` instead of `copydir` command.

So, instead of

```
<copydir src="../image_files/Ace/drawable-hdpi" dest="../IgnitorACE/res/drawable-hdpi"/>
```

use

```
<copy file="../image_files/Ace/drawable-hdpi" tofile="../IgnitorACE/res/drawable-hdpi"/>
```

Also go through the [official link](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) for more details.

Comment: I have used the above tag along with overwrite = "true"

Comment: Glad to see it worked. :) However, there is one thing that i would like to mention: we are here to help each other but it's always good to first search such issues on Google. If you really cannot find a solution, then you should post your query here. I hope you understand my point. :)

Comment: this doesnt work. for the correct answer use:    
`<copy todir="${dest.dir}" ><fileset dir="${src.dir}" /></copy>`    
see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685442/how-to-copy-the-directory-using-ant)